# How to display line numbers in rdoc?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

How can I get rdoc to display line numbers? I know there is `-N` switch, however even with it I get just

```
# File config.rb, line 40
def port
  @conf[:port].to_a || DEFAULT_PORT
end
```

I would like to have line number before each line, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

It's a bug - thanks to your question, it has been fixed in [Rdoc 6.1.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/rdoc/versions/6.1.0).

If your `rdoc --version` is older than that, update it with `gem install rdoc -v 6.1`, or simply `gem install rdoc` to get the latest version. Alternatively, update/specify `rdoc` version in Gemfile if you use Bundler.

After the fix, `-N` option properly enables numbering for each line:

```
# File config.rb
40 def port
41   @conf[:port].to_a || DEFAULT_PORT
42 end
```

---

**Original answer below:**

Looks like it is currently possible only through a hack in RDoc source code. From `rdoc --help` :

> -N, --[no-]line-numbers
>
> Include line numbers in the source code. By default, only the number of the first line is displayed, in a leading comment.

Initially, I misunderstood and thought that inserting number of first line is the default, minimalistic behaviour for this option, that can be modified in some other way - like customizing in templates. Eventually I realized that `--no-line-numbers` does nothing :) So yes, it's clearly a bug.

In RDoc code, the [method responsible for inserting line numbers](https://github.com/ruby/rdoc/blob/cb375a3928df546c19c6ebf6b6092395d44e6d5b/lib/rdoc/generator/markup.rb#L87) can be found in markup generator. Unfortunately, as of version 6.0.1, it doesn't seem to be used at all. Quick fix to enable it manually:

1. Find location of RDoc source with `gem which rdoc` and `cd` to that directory
2. Edit `generator/markup.rb` - find `@add_line_numbers` variable and set it to `true` (line 68 in github source I linked)
3. Run `rdoc` again, lines in your source fragments should be numbered properly.

That's of course far from proper bugfix. As an exercise, I also tried to fix it with monkey-patch and then run RDoc through a Rake task. I eventually gave up when I realized that [RDoc::Task](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/RDoc/Task.html) doesn't even accept `-N` as an option :(

As a footnote - [YARD](https://yardoc.org/) does proper line numbering and it's enabled by default.

Comment: So if I understand correctly it's not possible without hacking on rdoc's source and if I want it to just respect `-N` I should make feature request towards rdoc's tracker? ; ps: I'm using the standard generator to html (I think that's darkfish?) ; ps2: I'm fairly new to rdoc (I don't usually comment my code) so my understanding of what "generator" is might be off

Comment: That's the only solution I have found so far. More proper way would me probably running rdoc through a Rake task and altering that variable from within task. I will edit my answer once I figure it out.

Comment: I reported the issue and apparently bugfix is under way https://github.com/ruby/rdoc/pull/630 . I will edit my answer when fixed version is officially released.

Comment: I see your's PR is merged to ruby master, i see it available in ruby 2.6.2

Comment: @zw963 PR wasn't mine, only the issue but thanks - I updated my answer.